# button group and textbox in middle in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating pager using bootstrap as given below using input-group.

```
+──+─+───+──+─+──+
│<<│<│ 1 │GO│>│>>│
+──+─+───+──+─+──+
```

but it moves the part after textbox on right side. 
Sample code is I have added at 
https://jsfiddle.net/386my76a/
Would there be any bootstrap's inbuilt solution or I need to fix it adding custom CSS (ex: float left for 2nd part)?

Comment: Do you want pager to take 100% width?

Comment: no, I want it want to be auto size. because its label's are dynamic. I mean user can display "First","Last" etc instead of "<<",">>".

Comment: any one have idea where I can post feature request to bootstrap for the question? I think it is general issue,

Comment: You can open the issue on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to set the minimal width of entire input-group (like `width: 1%;`) and wrap input field into `.input-group-btn` class:

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {margin: 10px;}
.pagination {width: 1%;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="input-group pagination">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">&lt;&lt;</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">&lt;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group-btn">        
            <input class="form-control" type="text" style="width: 50px;" value="2">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Go</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">&gt;</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">&gt;&gt;</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that works. any width work which is less than the actual width required. hope in v4 they provide such inbuilt style to mix up input and buttons. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap do have their own pagination class and you can directly use it to make your pagination.

```
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
 </ul>
```

You can check out this link here and it shows how it works:

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=pagination-with-disabled-and-active-state-01

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for providing alternate solution. I need input box in pager because its client's design. mainly to keep same pager style in mobile as well as desktop website.